JavaScript reload function infinity problem
in my code reload js function goes infinity times is it possible to do once, i already try if/else branch it doesn't help, here is my code (stackoverflow required words limit: hbjbjdbjbjhdjdbv)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
    <script>
        function playSound() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                
                document.getElementById('mySound').play();
                document.getElementById('mySound').addEventListener('ended', function() {
                    document.getElementById('mySound_2').play();
                });
            }, 500)
        }
        var reload_bool = true;
        function locationreload() {
            if (reload_bool === true) {
                reload_bool = false;
                location.reload();
            }
            else {
                
            }
    }

    </script>
</head>

...
</body>
</html>


Please help me reload my html file once

Remove locationreload() entirely? Why should your page reload at all?

Dude, i just need to reload it

You said that. Why not just call your method on page load? What is the purpose of forcing a reload?
